# XSLT output as XHTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xhtml

So I have an XML file validated by its DTD and now I have to make transformations with an XSLT that should output all the each user's page to an XHTML file. I was told that I should use a 'for-each' but well, how can I do so that I get as an output one file for each user? (each output file should be an XHTML file with the information a user, in total one file per user)

XML (sample):

```
<store>
<users>
      <user id="user1">
            <name username="user1">User 1</name>
            <email>user1@email.com</email>
            <birth birth_date=""></birth>
            <mob_number>123</mob_number>
            <address>Street1</address>
            <picture></picture>
            <basket></basket>
      </user>

      <user id="user2">
            <name username="user2">User 2</name>
            <email>user2@email.com</email>
            <birth birth_date=""></birth>
            <mob_number>123</mob_number>
            <address>Street1</address>
            <picture></picture>
            <basket></basket>
      </user>

      <user id="user3">
            <name username="user3">User 3</name>
            <email>user3@email.com</email>
            <birth birth_date=""></birth>
            <mob_number>123</mob_number>
            <address>Street1</address>
            <picture></picture>
            <basket></basket>
      </user>

      <user id="user4">
            <name username="user4">User 4</name>
            <email>user4@email.com</email>
            <birth birth_date=""></birth>
            <mob_number>123</mob_number>
            <address>Street1</address>
            <picture></picture>
            <basket></basket>
      </user>
</users>
</store>
```

Thank you

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#creating-result-trees

Comment: How should the output look like and what did you try so far?

Comment: The output should be an html page for each user. Each page should have the info of a user.

Answer (score 0):

As @MartinHonnen noted, `xsl:result-document` is the way to go.
This answer outputs each `user` as a separate file named `HTML_userX`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/store/users">
      <xsl:for-each select="user">
        <xsl:result-document href="{concat('HTML_',@id)}" method="xhtml">
          <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:result-document>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes I try that, but whenever I run it I get the following error in IntelliJ: ERROR:  'Unsupported XSL element '

Comment: @ArmanFreitas: You need at least an XSLT-2.0 processor for using `xsl:result-document` which is required for splitting one XML file into many.

Comment: So, I'm kinda lost and a noob to this, what shall I do then?

Comment: @ArmanFreitas: use an XSLT-2.0+ processor like [Saxon](https://www.saxonica.com/welcome/welcome.xml).